# Find a match outside nested brackets with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find all occurences of `AND` word that are outside of brackets. I've tested a bunch of solutions from SO, but couldn't find anything that would work with nested brackets.

These ANDs should be found:

```
text AND text AND [ text AND text [ AND text [ text AND text ] text ] ] text AND text
     ^^^      ^^^                                                            ^^^
```

My best attempt was using this pattern `AND(?![^[]*\])` and it works fine until there are nested brackets

```
text AND text AND [ text AND text ] text AND text
```

Comment: Where is the regex used? Not every regex supports matching nested brackets.

Comment: Which programming language do you use here?

Comment: I'm coding on C#, testing on regex101.com

Comment: So that is your first mistake: regex101 does not support .NET regex. Whatever you try there won't work. What are you doing with the matches? Replacing? Extracting? Splitting?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Splitting

Comment: You need custom C# code to do that. That means, you'd better write some parsing function to get what you need. Regex is not going to help you much.

Comment: I somewhat disagree with @WiktorStribiżew, its easier if you split the process up, instead of attempting to do it all in one regex. See my answer as to how to *handle* the items to use in your scenario to build upon that.

Answer (score -2):

.Net Regex has the ability to use Balanced Pattern Mapping. What that allows us to do is match start anchor, to a corresponding finish anchor. .Net Regex uses the actions of *push* and *pop* which are done using named match captures. So one names the initial match capture, standard `(?<NameHere> )`, and the uses a `-` by the name to do the pop. Such as `?<-NameHere> )`.

There is no crime in chaining operations and I would make this a multi-part regex scenario.

1. Extract the text before and after.
2. Count the Ands in the before an after text.

For step one, I will put the preceding text in the named match capture "Pre" and the following text in the "Post".

This is the regex using balanced pattern matching. This pattern needs `IgnorePatternWhitespace` which allows for commenting of the pattern. Also to make it readable, I will use the hex value representations for `[` and `]` since they are regex pattern special characters.

```
var data = "AAA AND BBB AND [ EEE AND FFF [ AND GGG [ HHH AND III ] JJJ ] ] YYY AND ZZZ";

var pattern = @"
# 5B [ Opening bracket
# 5D ] Closing bracket

^                  # Anchor to beginning of the string.
(?<Pre>[^\x5B]+)   # Get the initial text before the first brace.
  (?<Brace>\x5B)   # Push the initial brace
    .+             # Extract all (including sub braces)
  (?<-Brace>\x5D)  # Pop the matching closing brace to the initial brace
(?<Post>.+)        # Get the follow-on text.
";

var mainMatch = Regex.Match(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);  

var totalAnds = Regex.Matches(mainMatch.Groups["Pre"].Value, "AND").Count
                  + Regex.Matches(mainMatch.Groups["Post"].Value, "AND").Count;

Console.WriteLine($"There are {totalAnds} Ands");
```

The result is `There are 3 Ands`.

Comment: This is super useful! It's a very detailed response, thank you! That's almost what I'm looking for, I will try to work around it to make it work with multiple top-level brackets. Such as `AAA AND BBB [ EEE AND FFF [ AND GGG ] JJJ AND ] CCC AND HHH [ EEE AND FFF [ AND GGG ] JJJ ] ZZZ AND`